# How to escape comma character in settings.xml

Tags: java, xml, maven

I have a comma character inside password in settings.xml.

When i run `mvn clean install` i getting:

```
[FATAL] Non-parseable settings /Users/user/.m2/settings.xml: entity reference name can not contain character ,' (position: START_TAG seen ...<password>Pass&ujm8ik,... @8:36)  @ /Users/user/.m2/settings.xml, line 8, column 36
```

settings.xml:

```
...
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>internal</id>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>Pass&ujm8ik,</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
...
```

Any idea how to escape comma?

Comment: Try `<password>Pass&amp;ujm8ik,</password>`

Comment: It's not the comma, it is the `&` character (that starts an entity reference in an XML file) which must be replaced with `&amp;`

Comment: `<password><![CDATA[Pass&ujm8ik,]]></password>`

Comment: Not quite sure why it thinks the comma is the problem. My guess is that it's waiting for the closing `;` for the entity that it thinks the `&` denotes, and the comma is the last character in the node. @ElliottFrisch's solution is the correct one actually (if it works) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Don't save passwords in open form in settings.xml:

```
% mvn --encrypt-master-password
Master password: <type master password>
{SJY1jWa2A+gHGOKW+C00brYbXkwRobSKFRiq6PunJVM=}

% echo -e "<settingsSecurity>\n  <master>{SJY1jWa2A+gHGOKW+C00brYbXkwRobSKFRiq6PunJVM=}</master>\n</settingsSecurity>\n" > ~/.m2/settings-security.xml

% mvn --encrypt-password
Password: <type server password>
{XiwnoYHLKakHh9jckhjjwVCci5azRRIZvS3snTmLdhc=}

% vim ~/.m2/settings.xml

    ...
    <server>
      <id>internal</id>
      <username>user</username>
      <password>{XiwnoYHLKakHh9jckhjjwVCci5azRRIZvS3snTmLdhc=}</password>
    </server>
    ...
```

See full guide in the official docs: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html